# HERE Maps Vector map in iFrame doesn't work - core.js issue

Tags: javascript, here-api

I have an application created with FileMaker and implemented Here Maps as a routing feature. I'm able to show Here Maps in my FileMaker Pro 19 client, although when I want to show the same map on iOS (FileMaker Go 19) or on the web (FileMaker WebDirect) I get the /iframeheight.js resource not found issue: https://a.cl.ly/qGuR94no

I have to put the maps in the iframe to show it correctly. The interesting thing is that it does show correctly the Satellite view, Traffic conditions, Traffic incidents, but when I need to load Map View (default) the background is grey: https://a.cl.ly/o0u7rlyZ

Also the Raster map loads up correctly as well, but I can't make the default map view to load up. So looks like the issue comes up only for Vector map in iFrame.

I'd appreciate any ideas how it could be fixed. Thank you!

Comment: We truly appreciate your letter asking for more information about our service.

Could you please help with the below checklist?

     1>sample code/code snippet
     2>Steps to Reproduce: What actions are needed to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello, thank you for getting back on this! 

I improved and totally minimised the code, in order to figure out where the problem could be. I overcome the 'iframeheight.js' issue, although I get the error from core.js now.

I've recorded a short video where I show my code and the errors with more details. Please watch it here: https://a.cl.ly/DOumjRLN

Again, I'd appreciate any help on this matter. Thank you!

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport is it possible you could look into my reply where I added more details about the code and the problem I get. I appreciate your reply. Thanks